# How to set system-wide environment variables in dockerfile from a file inside the docker container?

Tags: shell, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, docker-build

I am setting up a cross-compile environment as a docker container. During the build process I install a SDK for an embedded device:

```
ADD sdk.tar /opt
WORKDIR /opt/
RUN sdkinstall.sh
```

which installs the sdk in a folder `/opt/sdk/`

Now I have a file `/opt/sdk/envsetup` that contains some environment variables:

```
export SDKTARGETSYSROOT=/opt/sdk/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-gad-linux-gnueabi
export PATH=/opt/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-gadsdk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-gadsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-gad-linux-gnueabi:$PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT

.... and so on
```

Usually, when I would run a shell in the container I would do `source /opt/sdk/envsetup` and then compile stuff from the shell.

However, what I am trying to achieve is that all those environment variables are present system wide inside the docker container and are taken into account when I for example do something like `docker run -it xyz:latest make <somedir>`

I am testing this by calling `docker run -it xyz:latest echo $SDKTARGETSYSROOT` and I was expecting the container to print /opt/sdk/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-gad-linux-gnueabi`

What I tried to achieve this so far:

- Adding the vars to /etc/environment: `RUN cat /opt/sdk/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-gad-linux-gnueabi | cut -d" " -f 2 >> /etc/environment`
- Adding the vars to /etc/profile, /root/.profile and /root/.bashrc: `RUN echo -e "# Auto source some variables\nsource /opt/sdk/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-gad-linux-gnueabi" >> [...]`
- Adding one var manually in the dockerfile via `ENV SDKTARGETSYSROOT /opt/sdk/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-gad-linux-gnueabi`, just to test the behaviour
- `.` or `/bin/bash -c 'source'` the file `/opt/sdk/envsetup`

neither of those led to my expected result. How can I achieve those variables get setup properly?

As the file that contains the variables is unknown at the beginning of the `docker build` and gets created during the sdk installation inside of the container, I do not really like the idea of adding its content manually into the dockerfile via ENV, even if that worked, which did not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run this command:

```
docker run -it xyz:latest echo $SDKTARGETSYSROOT
```

The `$SDKTARGETSYSROOT` is expanded by your *local* shell. In no case were you actually testing environment variables inside of your container.  This would work:

```
docker run -it xyz:latest sh -c 'echo $SDKTARGETSYSROOT'
```

The single quotes inhibit variable expansion in your local shell, and we need to explicitly call `sh -c ...` because Docker does not, by default, execute commands using a shell.  Compare:

```
$ docker run -it alpine echo $HOME
/home/lars
```

With:

```
$ docker run -it alpine echo '$HOME'
$HOME
```

With:

```
$ docker run -it alpine sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```

Otherwise, several of your approaches look like a reasonable way to do what you want.

Comment: You were right about the missing quotes! Thank you.
For the general problem, the only solution I got to work was to define an `ENTRYPOINT` script in the Dockerfile that sources the variables each time I `run` the container.