# Docker: not being able to set env variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Nothing shows up for env var FOO even though I've set it:

```
$ docker run -e FOO=foofoo ubuntubr echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc
$ docker run -e FOO=foofoo ubuntubr echo $FOO
$
```

What did I do wrong?

But I was able to modify the path:

```
docker run -e PATH=/nopath ubuntubr echo $PATH
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"echo\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Then why isn't `docker run -e FOO=foofoo ubuntubr echo $FOO` isn't printing `foofoo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variables are set. The way you are trying to verify that they are set is wrong.

It's called "variable expansion" and I quote from the answer [@larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) has given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48403091/1561148):

```
$ docker run -it alpine echo $HOME
/home/lars

$ docker run -it alpine echo '$HOME'
$HOME

$ docker run -it alpine sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/root
```

1. it prints the `$HOME` variable of your host, not the container's. In your case `$FOO` doesn't exit on the host, so it prints an empty line
2. it prints `$HOME` (like a string)
3. this works, and prints the `$HOME` variable of the container

Example for your case:

```
$ docker run -e FOO=foofoo alpine sh -c 'echo $FOO'
foofoo
```

---

Thanks [@vmonteco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156085/vmonteco) for pointing out `docker inspect` for debuging. If you want to learn more on what your containers were actually doing, below are the `CMD` set for the 3 different cases discussed previously:

1. `"Cmd": ["echo"]`
2. `"Cmd": ["echo","$FOO"]`
3. `"Cmd": ["sh","-c","echo $FOO"]`

Comment: To complete this answer, you can also use `docker inspect container_name  -f "{{ .Config.Env }}"` to see the environment variables.